# Setstylesheet doesn't work niether for parent nor for the child

Tags: c++, css, qt

I have parent and child QWidget classes. I try to set some background color for them, but it doesn't work.

parent.h

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H

#define WRAPPER_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class Ping;

class Wrapper : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Wrapper(QWidget * parent=0);
    Ping * pingWidget;
    int resizedWidth;
    int resizedHeight;
    QHBoxLayout * hbox;
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * e);
    void  resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * e);
private:

};
```

child.h

```
class Ping : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    Ping(QWidget * parent=0);
    ~Ping();
    int w;
    int h;
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);
...
        };
```

parent.cpp

```
Wrapper::Wrapper(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMinimumSize(300,400);
    setGeometry(100,100,300,400);


    pingWidget=new Ping(this);
    pingWidget->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow ;};");
//doesn't work
        pingWidget->move((width()-300)/2, (height()-400)/2);
    setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow ;};");
//doesn't work  




    //QPushButton * b1=new QPushButton(this);
//if i add the button and change its color - it works     
this->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");


  //  user1->setGeometry(width()/10, height()/10, );



}
```

In one of the answers in the web i found that i need to put this code on paintEvet, so i did this - both for the parent and child.

```
void Wrapper::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{

        Q_UNUSED(e);

        QStyleOption o;

          o.initFrom(this);

        QPainter painter(this);
        style()->drawPrimitive(
              QStyle::PE_Widget, &o, &painter, this);
        setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow ;};");
}

void Ping::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * e)
{
    Q_UNUSED(e);

    QStyleOption o;

      o.initFrom(this);

    QPainter painter(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(
          QStyle::PE_Widget, &o, &painter, this);
    setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow ;};");

...
}
```

But still there's no progress. What should I do?

Comment: You attempt to set the style affecting QLineEdit only and complain about background color not set. Is there such class object there? Also don't do that from paintEvent and better don't try to make bothe paintEvent and style sheet working at once. Better try to separate this approaches and look at Qt examples for starters.

Comment: @AlexanderVX, Sorry, I don't understand. The stylesheet for the button works just fine, while the same code for the parent/child widget doesn't work (even when i include it in the constructor)..

Comment: QLineEdit is a specific type of control and the stylesheet intended to it, do you use that type? Also do not call setStyleSheet from paintEvent (overkill because setStyleSheet changes drawing!)